# Comprobar si existe antes de guardar en moongodb y nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Necesito guardar en mi base de datos MondoDB un array. Esto lo hago sin problemas con el siguiente código:

Mi array de objetos:

```
[ { name: '1', type: 'float', value: 89.05, timestamp: 1535440000 },
  { name: '10', type: 'float', value: 19.67, timestamp: 1535440000 },
  { name: '15', type: 'float', value: 1.7, timestamp: 1535440000 },
  { name: '17', type: 'float', value: 2.2, timestamp: 1535440000 } ]
```

Código guardar:

```
data_Greenhouse.collection.insert(data_inver, function (err, docs) {
      if (err){
        res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al guardar en la base de datos'})
      } else {
        console.log("Multiple documents inserted to Collection Data_Greenhouse");
        res.status(200).send({data_Greenhouse: docs})
  }
});
```

Necesito comprobar antes de guardar el array si en mi colección existe ya  para el campo name y para la fecha algún registro. Si existe no guardarlo y de lo controlario guardarlo.

¿Como podría hacer esto?

Un saludo gracias. Espero que este bien explicado es algo lioso.

> **EDIT01**

Edito el Post con un resumen de lo que necesito.

Realmente necesito pasarle a mi consulta el array de objetos y comprobar si existe y generar uno nuevo con los valores que no estén en la comprobación en la base de datos.

> **EDIT02**

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
data_inver.forEach(elem => {
   var Yaexiste = Data_Greenhouse.findOne({ 'name': elem.name,'timestamp':elem.timestamp}); // Realizas la busqueda en la DB para cada objeto sino existe, entonces lo inserta
   console.log('mostramos los valores: ' + elem.name +" " +  elem.timestamp);

   console.log('mostramos los valores: ' + Yaexiste[0]);

   if(Yaexiste==undefined){
     data_Greenhouse.collection.insert(elem, function (err, docs) {
     if (err){
      res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al guardar en la base de datos'})
      console.log("Error");

     } else {
      console.log("Guardado");
      //res.status(200).send({docs})
     }
    });
  }else {
    console.log('Los datos ya existen');
  }
  });
```

La respuesta que obtengo es la siguiente:

```
mostramos los valores: 653 1535440000
mostramos los valores: undefined
Los datos ya existen
mostramos los valores: 657 1518420000
mostramos los valores: undefined
Los datos ya existen
mostramos los valores: 8 1535440000
mostramos los valores: undefined
Los datos ya existen
```

Como ves no entra en el `if Yaexiste==undefined`

Solución final:

Si se comporta correctamente la añadiré como respuesta.

```
Data_Greenhouse.findOne({ 'name': elem.name ,'timestamp':elem.timestamp}, function (err, user) {
   console.log('mostramos los valores: ' + user);
   if(user==null){
     data_Greenhouse.collection.insert(elem, function (err, docs) {
     if (err){
      res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al guardar en la base de datos'})
      console.log("Error");

     } else {
      console.log("Guardado");
      //res.status(200).send({docs})
     }
    });
   }else {
    console.log('Los datos ya existen');
   }
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un arreglo con objetos a insertar:

```
var PorInsertar=[
 { name: '1', type: 'float', value: 89.05, timestamp:1535440000 },
 { name: '10', type: 'float', value: 19.67, timestamp: 1535440000 },
 { name: '15', type: 'float', value: 1.7, timestamp: 1535440000 },
 { name: '17', type: 'float', value: 2.2, timestamp: 1535440000 } ];
```

Recorres ese arreglo

```
 PorInsertar.forEach(elem => {
 var Yaexiste=data_Greenhouse.findOne({ 'name': elem.name,'timestamp':elem.timestamp}); // Realizas la busqueda en la DB para cada objeto sino existe, entonces lo inserta
 if(Yaexiste==undefined){ 
   data_Greenhouse.collection.insert(elem, function (err, docs) {
   if (err){
    res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al guardar en la base de datos'})
   } else {
    console.log("Guardado");
   }
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: Hola, este si tiene muy buena pinta y es lo que necesito, por alguna razón no entra en el if de undefined, es posible que cuando no encuentra el registro de otra información?

Comment: intenta haciendo un console.log de Yaexiste, si encuentra el registro entonces Yaexiste contiene la informacion del registro que estas buscando pero si no lo encuentra entonces el unico valor que se obtiene en Yaexiste es null o undefined

Comment: Eso estoy intentando pero me devuelve un objeto,    console.log('mostramos los valores si estan repetidos: ' + Yaexiste); resultado: mostramos los valores si estan repetidos: [object Object]

Comment: Significa que ese dato ya existe, para verlo utiliza: console.log('mostramos los valores si estan repetidos: ' + JSON.stringify(Yaexiste));

Comment: Eso lo he probado antes y me da este error TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>) 

Cosa que nunca me paso

Comment: Es imposible que el dato exista si he borrado todos los documentos de la BD, es lo que no entiendo.

Comment: Te mostraria ese error de Converting circular si tu busqueda fuese data_Greenhouse.find({...}) , pero no tendria porque si lo usas como un findOne, podrias poner las modificaciones a tu codigo

Comment: Edito el post y pongo las modificaciones de mi codigo. He conseguido con el    console.log('mostramos los valores si estan repetidos: ' + Yaexiste[0]);
mostramos los valores: undefined

Comment: Vale he visto que la respuesta de undefined es por que no encuentra esa posicion en el array no por la busqueda, confusion mia

Comment: Veo todo el código bien excepto lo de Yaexiste[0], para hacer pruebas quita el timestamp y pon los tipos de datos de tu coleccion

Comment: Hola, parece ser que he encontrado la solución, parte era al asignarle a la variable Yaexiste el valor de la respuesta de la busqueda. Edito el post y pongo el resultado, tambien he cambiado por NULL la confirmación. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si te ha sido de ayuda favor de marcar la respuesta como valida, Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Bueno efectivamente tienes que crear una consulta previa para ver si existe o no:

```
data_Greenhouse.findOne({ 'collection.name': '10' }, 'type value', function (err, data) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  aquí llamarias a la función que contiene el insert
});
```

Ahí tienes el código para buscar con un callback, como veras esta los parámetros de salida **err** y `data`, tienes que evaluar `data` ya que el te dirá si existe o no el dato que estas buscando.

---

Estoy escribiendo otra respuesta donde te complemento tu duda en un comentario a una respuesta previa:

```
data_Greenhouse.find({}, 'name, type value', function (err, data) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  //Aquí puedes recorrer cada registro
  data.forEach(function(dato) {
      console.log(dato)
  });
});
```

Tendrias que evaluar **data** para ver que indice de ese array te muestra o contiene los registros para luego hacer el **forEach**

Tambien puedes ser más especifico en la consulta puedes hacer esto:

```
data_Greenhouse.collection.find({}, 'name, type value', function (err, data) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  data.forEach(function(dato) {
      console.log(dato)
  });
});
```

Si la tabla es muy grande como me dices, para esos usas el filtro dentro del método **find** ejemplo:

Si buscas en la tabla algun registro donde tenga como **name** 10 usas este:

`data_Greenhouse.find({'collection.name': '10'}, 'name, type value', function (err, data) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);`

```
  //Aquí puedes recorrer cada registro
  data.forEach(function(dato) {
      console.log(dato)
  });
});
```

Con el filtro corroboras si existe un registro igual al que vas a insertar

Comment: Pero como puedo hacer para que en el valor de name y type recorra cada uno de los objetos de mi array? no solo el 10, todos.

Comment: Bueno puede hacer esto: data_Greenhouse.find({}, function(err, data) {
 
    data.forEach(function(dato) {
      aqui puedes obtener el valor de cada registro
    });

  });

Comment: Si la tabla es muy grande como me decias para eso usas el filtro en la método find, lo usarias asi data_Greenhouse.find({'collection.name': '10'}, ...,  en este caso estoy filtrando por name pero puedes filtrar por lo que te de la gana y asi no te traes todo sino parte de esa tabla